# javascript sort DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, dom

I have some element need to be sorted.

```
<div id ="list">
    <span data-index= "11">
        <table>
            <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
        </table>
    </span>

    <span data-index= "1">
        <table>
            <tr><td>deftd</td></tr>
        </table>
    </span>

          <span data-index= "5">
        <table>
            <tr><td>ddd</td></tr>
        </table>
    </span>
</div>
```

I had this code to sort it:

```
function sortChildren(wrap, f, isNum) {
    var l = wrap.children.length,
        arr = new Array(l);
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
        arr[i] = [f(wrap.children[i]), wrap.children[i]];
    arr.sort(isNum
             ? function(a,b){ return a[0]-b[0]; }
             : function(a,b){ return a[0]<b[0] ? -1 : a[0]>b[0] ? 1 : 0; }
            );
    var par = wrap.parentNode,
        ref = wrap.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(wrap);
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) wrap.appendChild(arr[i][1]);
    par.insertBefore(wrap, ref);
}

sortChildren(
    document.getElementById('list'),
    function(li) { return +li.dataset.index; }
);
```

This code work fine at google chrome but IE cause a problem to me. When i turn IE into compatibility view, the code cant work and show me the error as below:

```
Unable to get property 'index' of undefined or null reference
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: My IE current version is 11, turn to compatibility view become 7.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLElement.dataset is supported from IE11 on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

you have to use other ways to get the "data-index" value: `$(li).data("index")` using jquery for example or li.getAttribute("data-index") in plain js

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function. If this doesn't work, you could use `title` attribute instead of `data-index`.

```
function sortChildren(wrap, func) {
    var children = new Array();
    wrap.children().each(function(){
        children[func(jQuery(this))] = jQuery(this).html();
    });
    wrap.html('');
    jQuery(children).each(function(index, element){
        wrap.append(element);
    });
}

sortChildren(
    jQuery('#list'),
    function (element) { return parseInt(element.attr('data-index')); }
);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/5roe882y/**